# How can I change my Gmail nickname?

Tags: gmail

My email is for example "JaneDoe@gmail.com" and I noticed that when I write a new email to myself and I begin typing my own email it says ex. "CrazyJane" which is a dumb name I had originally chosen when I was 11 (currently 21). So on my Google+ account I have already changed my name to "Jane Doe". My question is, how do I change that dumb nickname so that it's completely gone?

Answer (score 2):

To check what name is being used for mail you send (and to change that name):

1. Open Gmail.
2. Click the settings cog in the upper-right.
3. Select Settings in the dropdown.
4. Go to the "Accounts and Import" tab.
5. There you will find the name that is currently being used. Check if that is the name you want to be used.
   [image]
6. If not, click "edit info" and change it to whatever name you want in the popup window.

Even if you do change your name, it's possible that other people who have received emails from you before have your old nickname cached already in their mail client and/or contacts. Some of these clients might update your nickname if you send them an email with your new nickname, but apart from that, there's not much you can do to get other people's mail/contacts clients to update your nickname on their end.

Answer (score 1):

I went on to google and changed the first and last name and it got rid of my embarrassing nickname, then I changed it back to my name.

Answer (score -1):

https://aboutme.google.com/
Go there and remove it. I had to fiddle around but finally got it sorted out.